# msys32 issue "pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-python2: - requested URL returned error: 404 while setting up ESP-IDF for use in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, esp32, esp-idf

I am trying to follow instructions to install Espressif 3.3.5 for ESP-WROVER-KIT which will ultimately allow me to do development using the Eclipse environment.
The first thing was to setup the toolchain:  Standard Setup of Toolchain for Windows which suggests downloading:
https://dl.espressif.com/dl/esp32_win32_msys2_environment_and_toolchain_idf3-20201104.zip         which supposedly "it will create an msys32 directory with a pre-prepared environment."
I did this and unzipped to C:\ as suggested which added the directory C:\msys32.
I created the ~/esp directory as directed and was able to cd ~/esp which supposedly means I am done with the "Toolchain setup".
Then the next step is the "Get ESP-IDF" which involves:
"git clone -b v3.3.5 --recursive [https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git"](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git%22)
which seemed to run successfully (no errors were seen).
The next step was to "Setup Path to ESP-IDF" which I did, following a link to the instructions to
set it up "permanently by defining IDF_PATH in user profile" which consisted of
creating file "export_idf_path.sh" in "C:/msys32/etc/profile.d/" directory containing:
export IDF_PATH="C:/msys32/home/rex/esp/esp-idf"
which I verified by closing the console, re-opening it and entering "printenv IDF_PATH"
This link instructed me to go back to the "Start a Project", however, that would skip the section labeled "Install the Required Python Packages".  I tried to install the python packages using the recommended command in this section: "python -m pip install --user -r $IDF_PATH/requirements.txt" but that indicated there was no python in the path.  Although there is at least one python on the computer.  I tried unsuccessfully to find one that would work and finally tried to issue the command "pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-python2" with the result that each site returned the "404" error.

Now for the question(s)...

1. DO I need to do this step since the instruction "go back to the Start a Project" would have skipped this step.
2. Assuming I do need to do this step, how do I get a python (not sure if it requires 2 or 3 but it seems that 2 should work) so I can install the items in the requirements.txt which contains:

```
# This is a list of python packages needed for ESP-IDF. This file is used with pip.
# Please see the Get Started section of the ESP-IDF Programming Guide for further information.
#
setuptools
# The setuptools package is required to install source distributions and on some systems is not installed by default.
# Please keep it as the first item of this list.
#
pyserial>=3.0
future>=0.15.2
cryptography>=2.1.4
pyparsing>=2.0.3,<2.4.0
```

Thanks for your help.
P.S. I already have the Arduino IDE 2.7.1 installed and have also installed the slober version that works with eclipse.  In addition, I have used eclipse for other projects successrully.

Comment: ESP-IDF 3.3.5 is quite an old version, and Python 2 has been deprecated for 4 years, so it's not surprising that some of these dependencies may not be easily available today. Do you absolutely need that old a version of ESP-IDF? You'll have a much easier time installing a more recent one.

Comment: Thanks for your information.   I was following instructions on a getting started page.  I am starting new so dont have a need for anything except whatever is required to be able to develop software for the dev kit I am using.  I have gotten the latest version working with the ESP32-C6-DevKit and  I will also be developing using a ESP32-WROVER kit and hopefully the same esp-idf will work, except for some configuration changes for the different kit.